# How to insert into database every x seconds, but that the user cannot change time to the inspect element?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I want to insert 1 point into the database every x seconds, but I don't want to allow a user that he can speed up that time into inspecting element. How can I do that?

```
var time = 1;
    var interval = setInterval(function() { 
        if (time != time + 1) {
                //some ajax code for sending points into database    
            time++;
        }   
    }, 5000);
```

This code is what I looking for but user easy can change this 5000 to etc. 500 and speed up the process of getting point. Is there any way to prevent the user from changing that time?

Comment: The user has access to your code?

Comment: How does the user have the ability to change it?

Comment: @Sharon he mean to say user can type in browser console to do the same.

Comment: This should be handled server-side, and the server would just keep updating the client.

Comment: If you need to do this I'd suggest using the observer pattern along with Websockets/Server Sent Events with server-side logic to control the intervals. AJAX polling isn't ideal.

Comment: _“I want to insert 1 point into the database every x seconds”_ - probably not the best idea to begin with; regarding a) performance, and b) reliability of the results (how much would it matter if one of these requests, or several, would fail, and you get a skewed point count based on that?) If you just want to award the user points for some kind of time-based activity – then you should rather record start and end time, and _calculate_ how many points that would give them whenever you need that value.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assuming that your ajax calls a PHP page, you should rate limit within the PHP (server-side) so that it cannot be modified by the user.

As it has been pointed out in the comments to your question, this task isn't well suited to ajax as it will constantly open and close connections which can degrade network performance and could trigger a [WAF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_application_firewall) to start blocking those requests. You should use a [WebSocket](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket) instead or send your data in bulk via ajax at a slower rate.